# Unknown type '245 in column

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I am getting below error while trying to update json object data in mysql.

```
error: 'Unknown type '245 in column 4 of 5 in binary-encoded result set.'
ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 - Unknown type '245 in column 4 of 5 in binary-encoded result set.
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 - 
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2374)
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2344)
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2322)
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:247)
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:138)
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/08/02 03:25:28 - Table input 3.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

could any one help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: catch your exception's error stack and add it to your post

Comment: added ravinder ,thaks for your response

Comment: can you please help me out to solve this issue

Comment: Unless you get the sql statement, no one can answer this question. If the `select` statement is generated at runtime, try to find it out and add to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Column type `245` refers to the `JSON` data type, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

I assume your driver is not up to date with this (new in `5.7`) data type.